# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in android.view.WindowManagerGlobal

Tags: android, indexoutofboundsexception

I have received this error in my remote app crash reporter:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.closeAll(WindowManagerGlobal.java:325)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3590)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3756)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:150)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1286)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Is this a known bug in Android? I have no more information about the crash. Do you have any idea about what can I do to get the cause?

Comment: Not without your code and a testcase, no.

Answer (score -2):

Array index start at 0

you have to subsract 1

Comment: The OP doesn't make the call. `android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.closeAll` does...

Comment: Why ??? [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15624552/java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-length-1-index-1

Comment: at .. is not the reason of the crash and  log is incomplete

Comment: What on Earth are you talking about? Yes it is and no it isn't.

Comment: Sorry but not understand your anger, i just try reply to the question wiih my experience and i know that arrays in java start at 0  caused by ??? we need to see the code or more log to determine it

Comment: I'm not "angry"; I'm confused by your insistence. Everybody knows that array indices start at 0 — that is basic knowledge.

Comment: I have seen more information in the log. It is beacuse of Dialog management: the `Activity has leaked window...` typical error.